# Can I have more than 1 function block in a Fuzzy Inference System?

Tags: java, fuzzy-logic

I'm creating an application for my university course that will use fuzzy logic to take input from a user and give a fuzzified output which will then be used to create a query of some sort.
I'm wondering if you can have more than one function block in the Fuzzy Inference System? For example, I take input of field 1 and field 2 and pass them to the FIS to then have the FIS deal with field 1 in function_blockno1 and to have field 2 dealt with in function_blockno2. The FIS would then return two seperate fuzzified numbers for use creating a query.
PS. Wasn't completely sure this is the correct place to post this so sorry if I got that wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you mean 'inference engine' with its set of inference rules when you say 'function block'. Your requirement seems to be a Multi Input Multi Output FIS. It is possible to create such an inference system by aggregating outputs from Multi Input Single Output inference systems. Therefore, it is fine to have more than one function block (inference engine) in your FIS.

[Fuzzy Logic With Engineering Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119235863) covers one such popular example of Airplane altitude control in Chapter 13.

More theory can be covered [here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/52551/)